# Remove the highest number in a list and print

Tags: python, list

I have created a function that takes a users scores, removes the worst one (highest) adds the rest of the list together and prints the score. Beneath is the code, when I try to run this in sublime i receive no output.

```
def SailorsResults():    
    tony = []
    tony = [3 ,3, 1, 1, 2, 6]
    tony.remove(max(tony))
    print(tony)
```

All i wish for this to do is take the list, remove the worst score, and add the rest up.

Comment: what language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is a function. To execute the code of a function, you have to call it.

For instance, in your case:

```
def SailorsResults():    
    tony = []
    tony = [3 ,3, 1, 1, 2, 6]
    tony.remove(max(tony))
    print(tony)

SailorsResults()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add the remaining numbers together:

```
def SailorsResults():
    tony = [3 ,3, 1, 1, 2, 6]
    tony.remove(max(tony))
    print(sum(tony))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the total, you could do

```
def sailor_score(times):
    return sum(times) - max(times)

tony = [3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6]
print(sailor_score(tony))
```